# Changing The Alpha Property Of Some Labels As A Result Of A Random Number In Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4

I need to change the alpha property of some labels as a result of a random number generation and I don't know hot to identify those labels in order to call them in the code.

For example:
If the number generated is 1, change the alpha or hidden property of the label that contains the text "1" and so on.

I wonder if exists something like the javascript function GetElementById() in xcode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use **Tag**, you can try the example below:

```
UILabel * aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 160.0f, 30.0f)];
[aLabel setTag:1]; // Set tag here
[aLabel setText:@"1"];
[self.view addSubview:aLabel];
[aLabel release];

UILabel * newLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:1]; // Get the label here whit tag=1
NSLog(@"%@",newLabel.text); // Print the label text with right tag
[newLabel release];
```

But the tag can only be number.

Comment: And if you want set the alpha, just do it with the right label. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UIView tag property (which is an NSInteger), then identify your interface elements using that. Alternately, if you want to set the alpha depending on the UILabel text, you can do something like

```
NSInteger generatedNumber = 5;

if ([label.text integerValue] == generatedNumber)
    // set your alpha value
```

However note (of the NSString integerValue method) that:

> The NSInteger value of the receiver’s text, assuming a decimal
>   representation and skipping whitespace at the beginning of the string.
>   Returns 0 if the receiver doesn’t begin with a valid decimal text
>   representation of a number.

If that is a problem you can use NSScanner to convert the NSString to an NSInteger, which will allow you to detect conversion failure.

Answer (score 0):

suppose u want3 random no..then write something like this...

```
int counter = random() %3;
if(counter == 0)
{
//change alpha according to ur requirement
}
if(counter == 1)
{
//change alpha according to ur requirement
}
if(counter == 2)
{
//change alpha according to ur requirement
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the labels in an NSMutableArray, so you have a reference later. Or if you really don't wanna put them in an array for some reason, you can iterate through the subviews of your main view, and find the right label, like this:

```
    for (UIView *subview in [mainView subViews])
    {
         if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
         {
              if ([[(UILabel *)subview text] isEqualToString:@"1"])
              {
                    [subview setHidden:YES];
              }
         }
    }
```